# Starting a Chart.js Time Scale at 0

Tags: javascript, time, chart.js

In this Chart.js time scale, why won't "Mar 11" start at 0?
I'm trying to get it to start from the beginning at zero, but it's starting at a random time.
Any insight would be appreciated!

[image]

https://jsfiddle.net/askhflajsf/7yped1d5/ (uses the latest [master branch build](http://www.chartjs.org/dist/master/Chart.bundle.min.js))

```js
var barChartData = {
  labels: ["2013-03-09", "2013-03-16", "2013-03-23", "2013-03-30", "2013-04-06"],
  datasets: [{
    borderColor: "#3e95cd",
    data: [10943, 29649, 6444, 2330, 36694],
    fill: false,
    borderWidth: 2
  },
  {
    borderColor: "#ff3300",
    data: [9283, 1251, 6416, 2374, 9182],
    fill: false,
    borderWidth: 2
  }]
};

Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily = "'Comic Sans MS'";
// Disable pointers
Chart.defaults.global.elements.point.radius = 0;
Chart.defaults.global.elements.point.hoverRadius = 0;

var ctx = document.getElementById("bar-chart").getContext("2d");
new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: barChartData,
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    legend: {
      display: true,
      position: "right"
    },
    title: {
      display: false
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        type: "time",
        ticks: {
          minRotation: 90
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="http://www.chartjs.org/dist/master/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="bar-chart"></canvas>
```

Comment: I do not understand what you mean. The first datapoint is the 9th of March, and all the data has value greater than 0.

Comment: So there's no way to show the first date at 0 on the Y-axis? Looks a bit odd when the first tick starts way out there.

Comment: Found a solution for this one, not sure if it would be acceptable to you or not? Chart would look somewhat like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vl6S.png)

Comment: Thanks for getting back at me. I'm not sure though. According to the Chart.js author there's no real solution to this problem: https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/4679

Comment: Ya true there isn't.. mine was a partial solution..

Answer (score 1):

Seems this is by design, why dont you do a simple workaround to this. Use moment.js for doing the time manipulations and load the data into x axis as type **linear** instead of **date**, This basically gives the same output.

JSFiddle: [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Kai_Draord/bods8ngd/3/)

**Code:**

```
var timeOperations = ["2013-03-09", "2013-03-16", "2013-03-23", "2013-03-30", "2013-04-06"].map(function(value){
    return moment(value, "YYYY-MM-DD").format('MMM-DD').toString();
});
var barChartData = {
  labels: timeOperations,
  datasets: [{
    borderColor: "#3e95cd",
    data: [10943, 29649, 6444, 2330, 36694],
    fill: false,
    borderWidth: 2
  },
  {
    borderColor: "#ff3300",
    data: [9283, 1251, 6416, 2374, 9182],
    fill: false,
    borderWidth: 2
  }]
};
```

Comment: Hi! Unfortunately that doesn't seem to work very well with larger datasets: https://jsfiddle.net/bods8ngd/4/

Comment: @MarkBoulder oh, that's too bad, I guess working with date will be better, just need to mod the chart.js library and fix this, but the effort will be loads :(